# TypeScript: Creating new object type from array of objects

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way to infer the name value from an array of objects and have the new object use those values as keys for the output type?

```js
interface TypeA {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}

interface TypeB {
  [key: string]: { value: any };
}

// can this be created without hard-coding a new type containing the values?
interface OutputType {
  test: {value: any},
  test2: {value: any},
}

const arrayOfObjectsToObject = (array: TypeA[]):OutputType =>
  array.reduce((acc: TypeB, { name, value }: TypeA) => {
    acc[name] = { value };
    return acc;
  }, {});

const result = arrayOfObjectsToObject([ // {test:{value:1}, test2:{value:2}} etc...
  { name: 'test', value: 1 },
  { name: 'test2', value: 2 }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could define a generic type `ToOutputType` which takes a tuple and transforms the type to the desired object type using a mapped type.

```
type ToOutputType<T extends { name: string, value: any }[]> = {
    [K in T[number] as K["name"]]: { value: K["value"] }
}
```

We also modify the `arrayOfObjectsToObject` to make it generic.

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

const arrayOfObjectsToObject = 
  <
    T extends { name: K, value: any }[], 
    K extends string
  >(array: readonly [...T]): Expand<ToOutputType<T>> => {
    return array.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
      acc[name] = { value };
      return acc;
    }, {} as any) as Expand<ToOutputType<T>>;
  }
```

`T` will hold the tuple passed to the function. `K` will be used to narrow the strings in the tuple to literal types. We use the type `Expand<ToOutputType<T>>` as the return type. The `Expand` type is used just to make the type prettier.

---

When you call the function, you get the following result.

```
const result = arrayOfObjectsToObject([
  { name: 'test', value: 1 },
  { name: 'test2', value: 2 }
]);

const a = result.test
//    ^? { value: number; }

const b = result.test2
//    ^? { value: number; }
```

Notice that the type of `value` is `number` in both cases. TypeScript automatically widens the numbers to `number`. To prevent this, we can use `as const`.

```
const result = arrayOfObjectsToObject([
  { name: 'test', value: 1 },
  { name: 'test2', value: 2 }
] as const);

const a = result.test
//    ^? { value: 1; }

const b = result.test2
//    ^? { value: 2; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcxyAbnADYCu1pXuQBG0NgF9ChUJFiIUGbACEC7ANoBrCOhr1GIJgF0a%20Tj3404IdMnESpAegfIEV5GAAWwWslEuoEHCQACbIAO7AngD2vGDIHnBQwQC0CFHBzMhwpBBh7lgoaeBwoJmeKFx8ELQA-IRgBWhRAPKxmLGKEAA8qMgQAB6QIME%20pmSUugzMADRmVZbWtmqGAHzIALyqJCRqANLIoGhqIEKiUIZZPrtqAETjEDeGxgRzFsjXN5X8j7aE4shSBrYZAAUX6mCswR6a02vQGQxGBxAMGgyGayBqLz2SOQWnQURgaOezT2F3%20NBAEA4YkBjQAcokoFEwnBhNwUJs9JkAD6CESo3nCKJRdluXm0dAiEXIXlRYQAKwgCDivN4wwgMFAEFCvI4UWAOsE3G4MoIdikRXoWSgUDg6GaMGaCqVYFoqBazuVGwBJC67BIcMGEGGo1IFAEu1mXwEVhs4mWs397z6QZDdCmBnYKwAFIy7TQAnBglEQNwbGoAHRV1CGACUNDBEOGPRabQ6BWhMLWRG2yACYF4UBA1tt6ArAWCvCQ2dzCAQszG4aj5hQ4lrG27SZIiAQx3DF02pmjtjYvZI-cHw53p%2024gX-zgPlj68foPBkJbrTA7TAnU7N8kEgLRLK0AloXhuDiTY83tR1PVdd0nUVZVszUdhFwmZAAHJIHoLDl3mZAAEZbGmdCw0wnDqjAAAmfDXgEGjfguV9LTAWs2EINism9MCILACtcLAQgnF7AA9TEjxXGgiJYX4uJAuJhF46p%20ME6iaJE5xtgkl5oxoGi5PEIA)

---

If you don't want to use `as const`, we can also use an extra *magic* generic type for inference.

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

const arrayOfObjectsToObject = 
  <
    T extends { name: K, value: N }[], 
    N extends { [k: string]: N | T | [] } | Narrowable,
    K extends string
  >(array: readonly [...T]): Expand<ToOutputType<T>> => {
    return array.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
      acc[name] = { value };
      return acc;
    }, {} as any) as Expand<ToOutputType<T>>;
  }
```

Comment: I think you forgot to change the types of a and b after using as const.